# Will there be any difference between 42, 42.0, "42.0", "42"

Tags: perl

During the process of testing my Perl code using "Smart Match(~~)" I have faced this problem. Will there be any difference between 42, 42.0, "42.0", "42"

```
$var1 = "42";
$var2 = "42.0";
$a = $var1 ~~ $var2;
```

I am getting `$a` as 0; which means `$var1` and `$var2` are not equal.

Please Explain.

Comment: No, they're all THE answer. ;)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The smart match operator will "usually do what you want". Please read this as "not always".

`42 ~~ 42.0` returns true.

`42 ~~ "42.0"` returns true as well: the string is compared to a number, and therefore seen as a number. Ditto for `"42" ~~  42.0`.

`"42" ~~ "42.0"` returns false: both arguments are strings, and these strings do not compare as "equal", although their numerical meaning would. You wouldn't want Perl to view `"two" ~~ "two-point-oh"` as true.

A string can be forced to it's numeric interpretation by adding zero:

`0+"42" ~~ "42.0"` returns true again, as the first string is forced to the number `42`, and the second follows suit.

The `perldoc perlsyn` or [`perldoc perlop` page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator) defines how smart matching works:

```
       Object  Any       invokes ~~ overloading on $object, or falls back:
       Any     Num       numeric equality         $a == $b
       Num     numish[4] numeric equality         $a == $b
       undef   Any       undefined                !defined($b)
       Any     Any       string equality          $a eq $b
```

You can see that string equality is the default.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to reconsider using smart match for now.  The current implementation is considered by the Perl community to be a mistake, among others because of your question and amon's answer.

Work is ongoing for a "saner" and simpler, but incompatible version of smart match which might be in the next major release of Perl (5.18).  It will simply outlaw your example: $a ~~ $b will not be allowed when $b is a simple scalar value (like 42 or "42").

If you have too much time on your hand, you could peruse the [Perl5 porters](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/) archives, for instance [this thread](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2012/08/msg190658.html).

Answer (score 2):

Contextual typing.

`$Var1` and `$Var2` were last used as strings (in the assignment) so now they behave as strings. `~~` will do string comparison if both arguments are strings.

If you **use** one of them as a number - you don't even need to assign to it - then it will behave as a number and `~~` will use a numeric comparison.

This script will output `NO YES`:

```
my $v1 = "42";
my $v2 = "42.0";
print (($v1 ~~ $v2) ? 'YES ' : 'NO ');

$v1 + 0;
print (($v1 ~~ $v2) ? 'YES ' : 'NO ');
```

[Reference for `~~` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Smartmatch-Operator)