# Comparing the values between two hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have two hash of arrays. I want to compare whether the keys in both hash of arrays contain the same values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings; use strict;
my %h1 = (
      w => ['3','1','2'],
      e => ['6','2','4'],
      r => ['8', '1'],
     );

my %h2 = (
      w => ['1','2','3'],
      e => ['4','2','6'],
      r => ['4','1'],
     );

foreach ( sort {$a <=> $b} (keys %h2) ){
    if (join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})
        eq join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})) {    

        print join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})."\n";
        print join(",", sort @{$h2{$_}})."\n\n";
    } else{
    print "no match\n"
    }
    }


if ("1,8" eq "1,4"){
    print "true\n";
} else{
    print "false\n";
}
```

The output is supposed to should be:

```
2,4,6
2,4,6

1,2,3
1,2,3

no match
false
```

but for some reason my `if-statement` isn't working. thanks

Comment: Your conditionals are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smart match is an interesting solution; available from 5.010 onward:

```
if ([sort @{$h1{$_}}] ~~ [sort @{$h2{$_}}]) { ... }
```

The smart match on array references returns true when the corresponding elements of each array smartmatch themselves. For strings, smart matching tests for string equality.

This may be better than `join`ing the members of an array, as smart matching works for arbitrary data*. On the other hand, smart matching is quite complex and has [hidden gotchas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12579160/will-there-be-any-difference-between-42-42-0-42-0-42/12579404#12579404/questions/12579160/will-there-be-any-difference-between-42-42-0-42-0-42/12579404#12579404)

---

*on arbitrary data: If you can guarantee all your strings only contain numbers, then everything is allright. However, then you could just have used numbers instead:

```
%h1 = (w => [3, 1, 2], ...);
# sort defaults to alphabetic sorting. This is undesirable here
if ([sort {$a <=> $b} @{$h1{$_}}] ~~ [sort {$a <=> $b} @{$h2{$_}}]) { ... }
```

If your data may contain arbitrary strings, especially strings containing commata, then your comparision isn't safe — consider the arrays

```
["1foo,2bar", "3baz"], ["1foo", "2bar,3baz"] # would compare equal per your method
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the warning messages? `Argument "e" isn't numeric in sort`

Comment: @cooldood3490 To sort alphabetically, use the `cmp` operator instead of `<=>`, or leave out the code block from the `sort`–alphabetic sort is the default

Answer (score 1):

```
if (join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})
    eq join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})) {
```

Should be :

```
if (join(",", sort @{$h1{$_}})
    eq join(",", sort @{$h2{$_}})) {
```

Note the `$h2`. You're comparing one hash to itself.

Comment: how do I get rid of the warning messages? `Argument "e" isn't numeric in sort`

Comment: @cooldood3490 Oh yea, that first sort should be `sort { $a cmp $b }`

Comment: @cooldood3490 `cmp` is for comparing lexically(alphabetically) and `<=>` is for comparing numerically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:It compares two hashes line by line exactly.

```
if (  join(",", sort @{ $h1{$_}})
      eq join(",", sort @{ $h2{$_}}) ) #Compares two lines exactly
```